# Jenkins does not show test results when releasing

Tags: maven, jenkins

Our jenkins CI platform does not show test results when we launch the maven build in release mode. However, when it is a normal build, it shows the test results section.

Is that a normal behaviour? Is there a way to display those results anyway?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Do you use the release configuration with (release:prepare / release:perform) ?

Comment: I use the following string for the build release: "-Dresume=false release:prepare release:perform" . I forgot to mention that the test reports are correctly generated inside the target directory of the project.